# Make multiple select comes under drop down option

Tags: jquery, html, select

This is my html code:

```
<form id="d-form" name="d-form">
            <div class="top-right-part">
                <select name="mytextarea" id="drop-down" multiple="multiple" size="1" width="250">

        <option value="leadership">leadership</option><option value="change">change</option><option value="patients">patients</option><option value="innovation">innovation</option><option value="medical">medical</option><option value="technology">technology</option><option value="training">training</option><option value="problem">problem</option><option value="experience">experience</option><option value="thinking">thinking</option><option value="challenge">challenge</option><option value="physicians">physicians</option><option value="Harvard">Harvard</option><option value="academic">academic</option><option value="skills">skills</option><option value="clinical">clinical</option><option value="science">science</option><option value="medicine">medicine</option><option value="opporunity">opporunity</option><option value="disease">disease</option><option value="information">information</option><option value="economics">economics</option><option value="china">china</option><option value="mentor">mentor</option><option value="quality">quality</option><option value="research">research</option><option value="mba">mba</option><option value="pharma">pharma</option><option value="nurses">nurses</option><option value="talent">talent</option><option value="knowledge">knowledge</option><option value="outcomes">outcomes</option></select>
                <button class="email_send"></button>
            </div></form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CtLBX/6/

Now its displaying the every value.I just want to display it under drop down options.Is there anyway in HTML itself.If no,What is the best jquery solution to acheive it.
Any help would be appreciated.Thank you!.

Comment: Are you asking like this.? http://jsfiddle.net/CtLBX/7/

Comment: Yes excatly can you explain the change I have tried this but its not worked for me

Comment: I'm guessing he/she still needs the multiple functionality. I'd look into this jquery plugin http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Comment: @user3580511 what's your requirement, please be clear.

Comment: I want multiple select functionality and also the drop down.

Comment: If you want multiple select functionality with drop down, then use autocomplete. That's the best option.

Comment: Although people have mentioned [**jquery multiselect**](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/), have a look at [**bootstrap multiselect**](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#examples) also. There is also a common place which gives list of plugins [**List Of Plugins For Multiselect**](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/multiple-select)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a multiple, you can't make it like a drop down. So you have two options:

- remove `multiple`
- set height like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CtLBX/11/

```
#drop-down{
    height:20px;
}
```

It doesn't look like a drop down but it will take the same amount of space and you can still select multiple values.

Something else you could do is make a faux select, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CtLBX/16/

CSS:

```
.mask{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height:23px;
    min-width:62px;
    vertical-align:top; overflow:hidden; border:solid grey 1px;
}

#drop-down{
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    margin:-18px -30px -18px -8px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.wrapper').click( function(event){
    if(true){
       $('#drop-down').show();
        $(".mask").hide();
    }
    event.stopPropagation();

});

$('body').click(function(){
    $('#drop-down').hide();
    $(".mask").show();
});
```

What this does is:

- add a `div` that will display the first value.
- when you click it a multi-select the drop-down will appear.
- if you click somewhere else it will disappear.

You will have to tweak it a bit for your needs but it will work.

You can find a more advanced version of what i posted above as a plugin [here](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) and [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#examples).

Comment: I want multiple select functionality and also the drop down.

Comment: Updated my answer with a way to achieve a multi-select drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the multiselect box to a drop down remove multiple="multiple"

Comment: I dont want to remove the multi select feature

Comment: I think this might help http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/